# ESP8266 12F doesn't work when programmed with arduino, but works fine with AT commands

Tags: arduino, esp8266, firmware

So, I got this webserver running using:
http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json
V2.4.1

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#include "index.h" //html page

const char* ssid      "xxx"       // WiFi SSID
const char* password  "xxx"  // WiFi password

//Creat object
ESP8266WebServer server ( 301 );

void handleRoot()
{ 
  String getPage = MAIN_page; // read html contents
  if ( server.hasArg("dir") )
  {
    handleDir();
  }
  else if ( server.hasArg("spd") )
  {
    handleSpeed();
  }
  else
  {
    server.send ( 200, "text/html", getPage );
  }  
}

void handleDir()
{
  String DirValue = server.arg("dir"); 
  Serial.println(DirValue); 
}

void handleSpeed()
{
  String SpeedValue = server.arg("spd"); 
  Serial.println(SpeedValue);
}

void setup()
{
  //SerialCom
  Serial.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1);

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED )
  {
    delay(500); Serial.print(".");
  }
  //Connection stable ok
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to: " ); Serial.println( ssid );
  Serial.print("IP address: "); Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  //????
  server.on ( "/", handleRoot );

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started" );
}

void loop()
{
  server.handleClient();
  delay(500);
}
```

After I updated the html page and flashed the esp8266 again (with Arduino IDE), for some reason, the esp8266 never connects to the wifi, therefore, never leaves

```
  while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED )
  {
    delay(500); Serial.print(".");
  }
```

Another thing that's intriguing, is that I only get garbage in the Serial Monitor at 115200 baud rate, and at 74880 I get some information about the board, "Serial.print("Connecting to "); Serial.println(ssid);" is garbage too, but the dots are well received.

So I thought my board was damaged for something I did wrong. Then I tried to flash the firmware (ESP8266_NONOS_SDK-2.2.0) again to test it with AT Commands. And all worked really fine, I could change the baudrate to any I wanted and still works fine, connected and disconnected to my wifi without problems.

I tried again with Arduino IDE, but the same error keeps appearing.

The last thing I remembered to do was use the "WiFi101 firmware updater" that comes with the boards manager of esp8266, but couldn't even get past the first point "test connection".

Any ideas? (sorry any error in my writting)

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/4242

Comment: Can you flash and test a demo Arduino sketch for ESP?

Answer (score 0):

Did the all damn thing again, and it worked just with arduino ide. My best guess (because I cant remember well) it was the "chrystal frequency" opcion, that was set to 40MHz, instead of 26MHz.

Answer (score 0):

esp8826 chip itself puts out something at 74880 when it restarts. how are you powering it? it could be that the signal level programming is different between the IDE and the stock AT firmware, if arduino is trying to max the signal strength it might not have the power to do so.